# For Regex, can IsMatch be used if the string is within a phrase?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm masking all credit card format within my C# page.  I'm using IsMatch to validate.  Here's an example:

```
var creditCardNumber = "This is master card number 5500000000000004";
var mastercard = new Regex(@"^(?:5[1-5][0-9]\d{1}|222[1-9]|2[3-6][0-9]\d{1}|27[01][0-9]|2720)([\ \-]?)\d{4}\1\d{4}\1\d{4}$");

if (mastercard.IsMatch(creditCardNumber))            
{
    String lastFour = creditCardNumber.Substring(creditCardNumber.Length - 4);
    result = "**** **** **** " + lastFour;
}
```

It only validates if it's a single entry for example 5500000000000004.  What if I want the credit card number to be asked even it's within a phrase or paragraph?

Thanks

Comment: Replace `^` with `(?<!\d)` and `$` with `(?!\d)`. Note the last four digits can be captured in the pattern, `(\d{4})`, and then you can get this value using `String lastFour = MastercardMatch.Groups[1].Value;` (you would need use `var MastercardMatch = mastercard.Match(creditCardNumber)` before and check if there is a match using `if (MastercardMatch.Success)`). However, it seems you just want `var MyText = Regex.Replace(MyText, @"(?<!\d)(?:5[1-5][0-9]\d|222[1-9]|2[3-6][0-9]\d|27[01][0-9]|2720)([ -]?)\d{4}\1\d{4}\1(\d{4})(?!\d)", "**** **** **** $2");`

Comment: You shouldn't *have* credit card numbers anyway. Make sure you read [the PCI standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard).

Comment: Thank you. It somewhat works but I want this results: Example This is master card number 5500000000000004 only.

Here's that I want: This is master card number **** **** **** 0004 only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need custom **digit boundaries**, `(?<!\d)` and `(?!\d)`, rather than `^` and `$` *anchors*.

Then, you do not need so many string manipulations, you may simply find the matches while capturing the last four digits into a separate capturing group and then use `Regex.Replace` to mask all but the four last digits:

```
var pattern = @"(?<!\d)(?:5[1-5][0-9]\d|222[1-9]|2[3-6][0-9]\d|27[01][0-9]|2720)([ -]?)\d{4}\1\d{4}\1(\d{4})(?!\d)";
var MyText = Regex.Replace(MyText, pattern, "**** **** **** $2");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5Cd%29%28%3F%3A5%5B1-5%5D%5B0-9%5D%5Cd%7C222%5B1-9%5D%7C2%5B3-6%5D%5B0-9%5D%5Cd%7C27%5B01%5D%5B0-9%5D%7C2720%29%28%5B%20-%5D%3F%29%5Cd%7B4%7D%5C1%5Cd%7B4%7D%5C1%28%5Cd%7B4%7D%29%28%3F!%5Cd%29&i=example%205500000000000004.%20What%20if%20..&r=****%20****%20****%20%242)

Note `{1}` are redundant and are removed from the above pattern.

Here, `(?<!\d)` matches a location not immediately preceded with a digit, `(\d{4})` is a capturing group with ID 2 (since there is another capturing group already, `([ -]?)`) and the replacement pattern is a string of asterisks/spaces and ends with `$2`, the placeholder for Group 2 value.

Comment: I'm not getting the correct results for this pattern = (?<!\d)3[47][0-9]{13}(?!\d)
Is there an issue?

Comment: @MaryReiaSundi The pattern is different, it only matches 15 digit chunks and does not contain any groups. What are your new strings and expected outputs?